# Why does this Java operation affect multiple variables in my program?

Tags: java

At the beginning of my method I create two 2d arrays of lists.

```
public int[][] acds(int[][] board, ArrayList<Integer>[][] domains ) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<Integer>[][] domainsLeft  = new ArrayList[9][9];
    ArrayList<Integer>[][] domainsRight = new ArrayList[9][9];
```

I populate these arrays with the following code:

```
    for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
            domainsLeft[r][c] = domains[r][c];
            domainsRight[r][c] = domains[r][c];
        }
```

Then, I find a partition point depending on the size of a particular list.

```
    int initLength = domains[rIndex][cIndex].size();
    int splitPoint = (initLength / 2);
```

And then I iterate through and remove items from the first half of one of the arrays, and remove items from the second half of the second array.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < initLength; i++) {
        if (i < splitPoint) {
            domainsLeft[rIndex][cIndex].remove(0);//<--HERE
        } else {
            domainsRight[rIndex][cIndex].remove(splitPoint); //<--HERE
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when I step through my code, the lines commented above (i.e. the removals) appear to remove values from all three of the lists (i.e. `domains[rIndex][cIndex]`, `domainsLeft[rIndex][cIndex]`, and `domainsRight[rIndex][cIndex]`).

It's been awhile since I have programmed in Java but my understanding is that each of the bolded lines should only affect the lists that the methods are called on (i.e. either `domainsLeft[rIndex][cIndex]` or `domainsRight[rIndex][cIndex]`—but not both).

Does anybody know why this might be happening? Am I missing something...?

I can post screenshots if that might help. Thanks

Comment: You never create new lists, you're just filling `domainsLeft` and `domainsRight` with references to the existing ones.  So when you modify them, you see that regardless of how you reference it.

Comment: As mentioned by all you are working on reference of same array list and hence you are facing this issue, change your logic to use add() method of arraylist to create as separate lists instead

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an `Integer` is not an `int`.

`Integer` is an object in which the primitive type `int` is stored thorugh boxing.

`int` is a `primitive_type`, you can assign it with the `'='` operator.

As every object, every Integer has an address, and by doing:

```
 domainsLeft[r][c] = domains[r][c];
 domainsRight[r][c] = domains[r][c];
```

you are assigning the **addresses**, not the objects. 
So now when you change one of them, the other also changes. Basically it's the same object in "two places".

You're gonna wanna clone it instead, or change your approach in some other way.

Since `Integer` is not a complicated object, you could just re box each `int` value to clone.

```
domainsLeft[r][c] = Integer.valueOf((domains[r][c]).intValue());
//...
```

Comment: Integer are immutables, so when you change one of them, it doesn't affect others. And in order to create new Integers, using Integer.valueOf(...) is far more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are facing issue because here you are doing shallow copy which means we just assign references so that same location will be pointed and whatever we make changes it will reflect over there.

Better if we learn this by an example.

```
System.out.println(domainsLeft[0][0]);
System.out.println(domainsRight[0][0]);
```

**Output of this is :**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

List list = new ArrayList();
    list.addAll(domainsRight[0][0]); //deep cloning

```
List<Integer> oldList = domainsRight[0][0];
if(oldList.size() > 0){
    oldList.remove(0);
}
```

Here we are doing two things in first we are creating new arraylist from the list present in array. In second we are removing an element from list present in array.

```
    System.out.println(domainsLeft[0][0]);
    System.out.println(domainsRight[0][0]);
    System.out.println(list);

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So here we can see that when we removed element from list present in domainsLeft it removed from all of its references but not form of list created using new operator because that is created using deep cloning[where we do not use references].